# Magento 1.9 lines will not translate

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have a magento 1.9 site in Dutch. To make the site Dutch I downloaded the Dutch language files and configured these to my needs. Now my whole site is translated in Dutch, except for some phrases. These are still in English and I can't figure out how to change them in Dutch.

After the checkout Magento sends you to a redirect page (payment succes). I cannot change the header of this redirect page to Dutch. Its the same with the print link on the bottom of this page. It says "Click here to print a copy of your order confirmation."

Can somebody help me out?

Smedia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to go to:
app/design/frontend/base/default/template 
or
app/design/frontend/default/template-name/template 
And search for succes.phtml. Inside this file you will find the text and can alter it to your needs.